# ¿Un atributo contraseña en una clase como lo pongo?

Tags: java

He tenido un examen y me han hecho poner un atributo contraseña. Yo lo he declarado como 
private String contraseña.

Mi duda es esta bien así o tiene algo mas?

y cuando tenga que poner por el main la clave hay alguna manera de que cuando la sette salga como ***** ? la idea es que yo sette el codigo por teclado y al pedir un to String por pantalla pues me deberia de salir **** y no se si quizás cuando lo sette tampoco debería de verse lo que yo escribo

```
public class CuentaPersonal {

    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    private int edad;
    private double irpf;
    private String clave;
    private CuentaBancaria cuentaBancaria1;

    public CuentaPersonal(String nombre, String apellidos, int edad, double irpf,CuentaBancaria cuentaBancaria1,String clave) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.irpf = irpf;
        this.cuentaBancaria1 = cuentaBancaria1;
        this.clave = clave;
    }

    public CuentaPersonal() {
        this.nombre = "";
        this.apellidos = "";
        this.edad = 0;
        this.irpf = 0;
        this.clave = "";
        this.cuentaBancaria1 = null;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public double getIrpf() {
        return irpf;
    }

    public void setIrpf(double irpf) {
        this.irpf = irpf;
    }

    public CuentaBancaria getCuentaBancaria1() {
        return cuentaBancaria1;
    }

    public void setCuentaBancaria1(CuentaBancaria cuentaBancaria1) {
        this.cuentaBancaria1 = cuentaBancaria1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CuentaPersonal{" + "nombre: " + nombre + ", apellidos" + apellidos + ", edad" + edad + ", irpf" + irpf + ", cuentaBancaria1" + cuentaBancaria1.toString() + '}';
    }

    public double retenciones(double irpf) {
           double retenido = irpf / 100 * (cuentaBancaria1.getDineroCuenta() + cuentaBancaria1.getPlazoFijo1().beneficioObtenido());
        return retenido;

    }

    public String diferenciaEconomica(CuentaPersonal p) {
        String resultado;
        double diferencia = this.getCuentaBancaria1().getDineroCuenta() - p.getCuentaBancaria1().getDineroCuenta();
        if (diferencia < 0) 
            resultado = "El cliente " + p.getNombre() + " " + p.getApellidos() + " tiene mejor economia. La diferencia de dinero entre las cuentas es " + Math.abs(diferencia);
        else
            resultado = "El cliente " + this.getNombre() + " " + this.getApellidos() + " tiene mejor economia. La diferencia de dinero entre las cuentas es " + diferencia;

        return resultado;

    }
}
```

Gracias

Comment: hola @carlos diaz, primero que llevas en tu código??, es necesario que la salida sea con ******** , me imagino que estas mostrando la información por consola, te recomiendo que siempre pongas el código en tu pregunta para que podamos y tu puedas entender que es lo que estas haciendo.

Comment: Si no pones el código que hiciste no te van a ayudar, tu pregunta queda como que estas pidiendo que te hagan la tarea. Sin código queda a lo que piense cada uno, por eso a las preguntas de este tipo las terminan cerrando o llenando de negativos ya que al basarse en opiniones pueden confundir a futuros usuarios que tengan el mismo inconveniente.

Comment: @carlos diaz, lo del código es para ayudarte a ti y a los demás usuarios cuando necesiten resolver una pregunta similar a la que expusiste, ademas de que una mayor cantidad de usuarios puedan dar otras respuestas a tu pregunta, y que no solo te resuelvan lo que estas pidiendo con un par de lineas de código, la idea de stackoverflow es entender el trasfondo y el contexto de las preguntas y respuestas, saludos y todos estamos para aprender.

Comment: No se trata de lo que preguntes o no. Se trata de que este sitio tiene unas normas y hay que cumplirlas, ni más, ni menos. No es un foro.

Comment: Carlos si queres recibir ayuda y que no "te fundan a negativos" tenes que ser claro con la pregunta. En realidad tu pregunta es bastante ambigua. Mostrar * en donde? por consola? en un control de un formulario? en la web? Declarar una pass es lo mismo que declarar cualquier otra cosa, es una variable. y es un string. Ahora, tene mas cuidado con tus comentarios ya que pueden levantarte flags por no seguir el codigo de conducta en los mismo. Tene en cuenta que esto no es solo para ayudarte a vos, es para ayudar a todos.

Comment: @gbianchi Gracias ya he concretado mas la pregunta

Comment: Cuando lo setees usando que cosa? un formulario? por consola? tal vez te parezca tedioso, pero la respuesta a todo eso es muy diferente. La pantalla es algo que ocupa muchas cosas...

Comment: pues lo setteo con un print por teclado y me sale por pantalla reflejado por donde salen los printi jaja no se si puede salir por otro sitio la informacion por eso no concreto porque tp se mucho

Comment: Pero todo eso, lo tenes que explicar. o sea.. sabes la diferencia entre una aplicacion de consola y una aplicacion digamos de windows? tu aplicacion usa algun tipo de control visual?

Comment: pues la consola es una consola de comando cunado pones cmd en ejecutar y la aplicacion de widnows pues supongo que cualquier programa. jaja no se la verdad. y control visual que va mi nivel no da para eso todo muy sencillo

Comment: Entonces tenes un programa por consola. Perfecto. Porque fijate que en tu pregunta no dijiste nada de eso. Realmente no se como evitar que se escriban caracteres en la consola (lo he visto hacer, no se como se hace, supongo habra que trapear los eventos de teclado antes que lleguen). Pero para lo otro, las respuestas son mas simples que la que te plantearon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

!Buenas! Hace tiempo tuve un ejercicio similar. El truco para ocultar una palabra o una serie de números, es utilizar el código ASCII. Que por cierto, te anoto aquí para que le eches un vistazo:

[Codigo ASCII](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/)

La clave es utilizar una variable auxiliar, donde con ayuda de un **.length** podamos recorrer la palabra original, en tu caso la contraseña, y en la otra variable almacenar la misma longitud de caracteres con, por ejemplo, el *****.

Te dejo un código sencillo, al que si le añades ingenio puedes jugar un poco con el, y también con ayuda del enlace que te he facilitado.

```
private String pass; //CONTRASEÑA
private String passEscondida; // VARIABLE AUXILIAR PARA GUARDAR LA PASS CON OTROS CARACTERES.

public Test(String pass) {

    this.pass = pass;
    this.passEscondida = "";
}

public void cambiarCaracter() {

    for(int i=0;i<pass.length();i++){

        if(pass.charAt(i)>='a' && pass.charAt(i)<='z'){
               passEscondida+='*';
    }
        }    
}
```

En este trozo de código es un método que solo te va a funcionar con minúsculas, he aquí donde debes de añadir tu ingenio para utilizarlo a tu favor.
Y el resultado seria este, desde el main:

```
    Test test1 = new Test("prueba");

    test1.cambiarCaracter();

    System.out.println("Palabra escondida: " + test1.getEscondida());
    System.out.println("Palabra original: " + test1.getPass());
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

!Espero que esto te ayude! Un saludo!

Comment: ¿Por que un voto negativo? Desde mi punto de vista, responde a su pregunta sea o no el mejor método de hacerlo.

Comment: Si te ha servido, por favor, marca como elegida :D

Comment: para que te valga en mayusculas o minusculas solo hay que ver donde meter un compareto ignore case auqnue como soy muy nuevo no entiendo mucho

Comment: En realidad no es una mala respuesta, pero tiene mucho para mejorar. para que usar dos variables en la clase para mantener nada? porque hay que llamar a un metodo para transformar la password? depende donde se muestre, el control lo puede hacer automaticamente, o alcanza con tener un getter que devuelva una cadena de la misma longitud que password que sean todos astericos. Fijate que si la password contiene numeros, tu metodo los va a mostrar. Las respuestas tienen que ser correctas, y por eso tal vez el negativo.

Comment: Si, es cierto que hay cosas que mejorar. La verdad que es lo primero que se me ocurrió y cogí de referencia un ejercicio similar que tenia. Gracias por la información y la corrección. Soy también estudiante, y a la vez que intento ayudar, aprendo también.

Answer (score 0):

Las password en cualquier clase, se guardan como strings. No hay otra forma de guardar una cadena de texto que no sea un string.

Sin embargo, es raro que guardes la password en tu clase. Cual seria el sentido? El usuario debe ingresarlo una sola vez, y una vez que la usaste la tiraste.

Siendo que esto es un ejercicio, ok, supongamos que guardamos la misma, se guarda simplemente como lo estas haciendo.

Ahora para no mostrarla (otra vez, cual seria el sentido), la estrategia mas simple seria que tu getter en lugar de devolver la misma, devolviera una cadena de astericos.

En general, ni siquiera se devuelve una cadena del mismo tamaño, si no que se devuelve una cadena pre fijada. Devolver la cadena del mismo tamaño que la password real implicaria dar información a un atacante del tamaño de la cadena que esta buscando.

Ahora, si el ejercicio lo pide, podrias simplemente en tu getter hacer lo siguiente:

```
public string getClave() 
{
    Return new String(new char[clave.length()]).replace("\0", "*");
}
```

Ahi armamos un string de un array de chars vacios del tamaño de clave, y luego reemplazamos los caracteres vacios por asteriscos.

Comment: muchas gracias. el problema es que no te puedo dar mas informacion porque es totalmente ambiguo no concreta nada entonces no se nada mas. Igual lo de los asterisco ni si quiera era necesario

Comment: @carlosdiaz entonces no tenes que hacer la pregunta en el sitio, tenes que preguntarle a quien te esta dando la clase. Nosotros no somos tu profesor, y no sabemos que espera o quiere con sus ejercicios.

Comment: pero todo tiene una explicacion ayer tuve el examen y mñn tengo el trimestral y no veo al profesor entonces quiero ir preparado para todo lo que pueda preguntar ya que me deja llevarme apuntes voy llevarme preparado todas estas cosas para en el examen decirle tiene que llevar esto